# Applying a diff file with git

Tags: git, github

So I was trying to use apply a diff file to my git dev branch. The diff I wanted to apply was this one here: https://github.com/mbabker/joomla-cms/compare/JHtml_move.patch

I used `git apply PATH_TO_PATCH.patch`

Now on trying to apply it I get a load of errors cumulating with a

```
fatal: git apply: bad git-diff - expected /dev/null on line 47
```

Thing is line 47 reads `--- /dev/null`

I saw on another forum somebody say there was a trailing white space after the `/dev/null` part but there isn't.

In case its any help I'm also being thrown errors of trailing white spaces on lines 9, 10, 11, 12 and 13 - despite their NOT being any trailing white spaces.

In any case the diff is being generated by git - I'm just copying and pasting it into notepad.

I've also tried using `curl https://github.com/mbabker/joomla-cms/compare/JHtml_move.patch | git am` but that just gives an error without specifying location.

[image: Error message from curl attempt]

Any ideas as to why its giving an fatal error when the line actually exists????

---

**Update to @IvanZuzak**
I tried adding in the `git am --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace PATH_TO_PATCH.patch` however I got first of all (as this was the downloaded patch) an error saying the email was invalid (it had been converted to html code) so I tried to fix that but it kept throwing it up every now and again. Then it said `previous rebase directory PATH_TO_GITHUB_BRANCH/.git/rebase-apply still exists but mbox given.`. So I found [this](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/git-help-previous-rebase-directory-td104464.html) which suggested removing the rebase-apply folder in the branches .git folder. So I did that and then I got the invalid email error again (despite I'd changed both ones away from the html formatted)

Comment: Copy/paste? Notepad? Serious? DOS line breaks are the problem, I bet. Try properly copying the patch file over.

Comment: Well I tried with curl first which failed - but when that failed yeah notepad. How do I copy the patch file over then?

Comment: Just save it as a file from your browser? CTRL+s is the usual keyboard  shortcut for saving the currently open webpage. Also, what error are you getting when the curl combo fails?

Comment: @IvanZuzak added a screenshot with the curl error. The patch moves to delete the two files mentioned there. And they definitely exist in the git project. I tried saving from the browser but just got a tonne more errors in a similar fashion for all the other files it was trying to delete.

Comment: @GeorgeWilson Can you try `git am --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace PATH_TO_PATCH.patch` and see if that works? Also, notice that there is a difference between using `git am` and `git apply`, and there is also a difference between using `https://github.com/mbabker/joomla-cms/compare/JHtml_move.patch` and `https://github.com/mbabker/joomla-cms/compare/JHtml_move.diff` (notice the patch vs diff file extension). `git am` works with .patch files, while `git apply` works with .diff (at least it should).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between the git am and git apply - makes sense :) I've updated my post above with the results of your test as it was too long to go in a comment. Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Just a guess - do you have this file "libraries/cms/html/contentlanguage.php" now? The patch assumes that there is no file and it should be created. It might fail if the file already exists.

Comment: when running git am --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace PATH_TO_PATCH.patch i got the error : Patch format detection failed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I also had the same problem:

```
fatal: git apply: bad git-diff - expected /dev/null on line 47
```

Yet line 47 reads `--- /dev/null`. The problem I found was that the line endings were in Windows format instead of UNIX format. Converting the line endings to UNIX format in Notepad++ fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Same here, except that I wasn't able to convert from the Edit>LineEndings (it said that I was already in Unix format). I had to find/replace \r\n to \n in advanced replace prompt.

Comment: This was my problem also. To convert line endings in Vim, open the file, run the command `:set filetype=unix`, then write the file and close. After doing that, the patch applied successfully for me

Comment: I also had the problem with line endings on Ubuntu. I installed dos2unix using apt-get install dos2unix and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I also had this problem and dos2unix didn't fix it. I had run "svn diff --git", and it had set the delete mode to 10644, which isn't valid. I needed to change it to 100644.

Comment: @NathanWallace :set filetype=unix did not work for me, I had to use :set ff=unix

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  I opened up Git Bash (Cygwin works as well) and did:

```
dos2unix.exe <patch-file>
```

Then I was able to apply the patch perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to check if you still see the error message `bad git-diff - expected /dev/null on line 47` after Git 2.17 (Q2 2018).

Many places in "`git apply`" knew that "`/dev/null`" that signals "there is no such file on this side of the diff" can be followed by whitespace and garbage when parsing a patch, except for one, which made an otherwise valid patch (e.g. ones from subversion) rejected.

See [commit e454ad4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e454ad4becff73588b1b3cc24dba3a0e740c7f7c) (15 Feb 2018) by [Tatyana Krasnukha (`tkrasnukha`)](https://github.com/tkrasnukha).
See [commit f16ef7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f16ef7bd4c37fba8c030b87610f646a1fce5d52d) (15 Feb 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 177bd65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/177bd65cf8601216e906ad56ceb6a46f57df22fa), 28 Feb 2018)</sup>

See also [git-for-windows/git issue 1489](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1489)

> ### `apply`: handle Subversion diffs with `/dev/null` gracefully
>
> Subversion generates diffs that can contain lines like this one:
>
> --- /dev/null  (nonexistent)
>
> Let's teach Git's apply machinery to handle such a line gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I was testing a patch I was going to send to a listserve, following the recommendations here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/email-clients.txt . I couldn't just fix the problem on my local file, I needed to distribute a patch which was potentially going to be mangled by gmail and I was checking the gmailed version with `git apply`.

My co-worker pointed out to me that

```
git am
```

Is better than `git apply` at correcting for these sorts of problems and is what should be used with `.patch` files. This is mentioned in one of the comments above but it should be an answer.

Comment: The `git am` documentation says that it applies patches from a mailbox...  how do you use it with a .patch file?

Comment: `git am 0001-example.patch` - I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem with this patch generated using `svn diff --git` (svn in version 1.14.1 (r1886195) running on Debian):

```
Index: bar.txt
===================================================================
diff --git a/bar.txt b/bar.txt
new file mode 100644
--- a/bar.txt   (nonexistent)
+++ b/bar.txt   (revision 6)
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+foo
\ No newline at end of file
```

i.e. what this patch does is create a new file "bar.txt" with contents "foo"

it gives the error (git version 2.30.2 running on Debian):

```
error: git apply: bad git-diff - expected /dev/null on line 4
```

I had to change `a/bar.txt` to `/dev/null` on line 5:

```
Index: bar.txt
===================================================================
diff --git a/bar.txt b/bar.txt
new file mode 100644
--- /dev/null (nonexistent)
+++ b/bar.txt   (revision 6)
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+foo
\ No newline at end of file
```

And then it worked.

Here is a (hackish) Python fix:

```
def fix_patch_bad_new_file(patch_path):
    inputfile = open(patch_path, "rb")
    data = inputfile.read()
    inputfile.close()
    data = re.sub(b'(.*)---(.*)\(nonexistent\)(.*)',
                  b'\\1--- /dev/null\x09(nonexistent)\\3',
                  data)

    data = re.sub(b'(.*)\\+\\+\\+(.*)\(nonexistent\)(.*)',
                  b'\\1+++ /dev/null\x09(nonexistent)\\3',
                  data)

    file = open(patch_path, "wb")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
You have a rebase in progress, write

```
git rebase --skip
```

many times, until see `No rebase in progress?`
then try again with `git am`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

`fatal: git apply: bad git-diff - expected /dev/null on line 96`

Or, if I convert all line-endings to Unix format:

```
error: patch failed: <file>:81
error: <file>: patch does not apply
...
```

`git apply --ignore-whitespace <patch>.patch` worked with Unix line-endings.