# Why is git apply patch command not working in powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I'm trying to extract some patches from my repository, and apply them to another branch in a different repository.

I am running this command to get the patch file:

```
git format-patch develop --stdout > changes.patch
```

which outputs the patch in UTF16-LE format instead of ASCII or UTF8, which seems to be the default hardcoded into powershell. So, instead I write this command:

```
git format-patch develop --stdout | Out-File changes.patch -Encoding ASCII
```

Which gives me the patch file. When I try to apply this patch file using

```
git apply --stat changes.patch
```

then git throws an error that `fatal: git apply: bad git-diff - expected /dev/null on line 18`. The patch file **does** have `/dev/null` on line 18, then why is the command whining about it? If I run the same command (git apply ...) in command prompt, then it works perfectly.

Is this problem related to UTF encodings?
How can I apply git patches in powershell?

Comment: actually, I don't know why I was even doing the `--stdout | out-file...` part. format-patch already outputs files. But still, this question is valid

Comment: What happens if you use `Encoding UTF8`?  What happens if you write the patch file from `git bash`?

Comment: Running the `git format-patch HEAD~ --stdout > patch.patch; git apply --stat patch.patch` work both in bash and cmd.exe. Running any variant in powershell fails. Although the files generated by PS and bash look the same, doing a diff reveals that all lines are different, meaning that probably the PS is writing `CRLF` instead of `LF` output by the format-patch command which is resulting in these errors.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49099317/6309